# Highcharts js Y axis start from last value

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm working with highchart and I have the following chart working.

[image]

However, I need the next value starts at the point of the previous value.

[image]

Can someone help me please?

I use this function to generate chart

```html
function generateChart(chartUrl, id) {
  let options = {};

  $.ajax({
    url: chartUrl,
    data: {name: id},
    success: function (data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;

        // Get categories dynamicaly, not harcoded
        for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          options.xAxis.categories.push(data[i][0]);
        }

      $(`#${id}`).highcharts(options);
    }
  });
}
```

And this code to Generate Data and Efects on chart

```html
function generateEfectsChart() {
  let options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
      lineWidth: 0,
      gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
      categories: [],
    },
    yAxis: {
      lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
      lineWidth: 0,
      gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
      plotBands: [{
        color: '#000000', // Color value
        from: 0, // Start of the plot band
        to: 0 // End of the plot band
      }],
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000000'
        },
        colorByPoint: true,
        pointWidth: 150
      },
      series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.y}'
        },
        turboThreshold: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      negativeColor: '#ED4D5F'
    }]
  };

  return options;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `waterfall` series type.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'waterfall'
    },
    ...,
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://www.highcharts.com/demo/waterfall

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/waterfall-series

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved my doubt :)